# Excluding external jar while generating a fat jar using spring boot maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I had created a spring boot application, using spring initializer. I had added some external jars to my class path using IDE. When i try to creating a jar, by maven clean and maven install, am getting

```
 package com.art.common.exception does not exist.
```

Do we need to add the jar dependency XML in pom.xml?

I dont want my external jar to be part of my jar, as i could get those in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use maven as your dependency manager you have to tell it that you are using that external dependency. If you don't want maven to download it you can marke the scope as `provided` and it maven will look for the `jar` in your `lib` folder.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, so do i need to add dependency xml and give the scope as provided? And i have like 50 jars

Comment: Yes you need to do that.

Comment: uff. and where can i find group id, artifact id for those jars?

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan Look inside the JAR under `META-INF\maven`. Otherwise Google. It can be, though, that these JARs are not distributed via Central Maven repo. There are ways to handle it as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Checked inside META-INF, there is no maven folder. What is the external jars not using maven?

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar as a dependency with scope ‘provided’ and if the jar is not found publicly on the maven central then use NCB install the jar to create it in your local repo ...